# Trying to develop a better understanding of UML diagram relationships

Tags: java, dependencies, uml, aggregation, argouml

This is my very first UML diagram for a Student Record System I have created. I've been reading documentation on the types of relationships such as dependency, Association and Aggregation. Any opinions?

[image]

[larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/limZS.jpg)

Comment: Ok sorry the image is a little small on here.  Right click -> Save as and it's much more clear :)

Comment: There is no aggregation in that diagram. There is only one association (which is a less specific aggregation) and a handful of dependencies. What, exactly are you looking for? A design review? UML notation help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some, of the top of my head:

1. Try to arrange it like a tree with dependency arrows going top to bottom. It makes it more readable and allows you to see where improvements can be made.
2. I think you have mixed up arrow direction. If class A makes calls to class B then class A is dependent on class B and arrow should be pointing from A to B.
3. If any class is going to keep an instance of another class then you need to use solid lines to indicate that. e.g. Class A has an instance of class B then use a solid line with arrow from A to B.

Answer (score 1):

If your relationships mean that a class references another class, typically solid lines are used.  Dotted-lines indicate a weaker dependency.

If you are using UML as part of documentation, including only the classes/methods of interest makes UML much more readable.